# Keras strange crash

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Training model in Keras I get exception at some epoch:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7f036d74b7f0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 686, in __del__
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What could be reason of such behaviour?

Comment: Is that the full traceback? Very hard to say from this alone.

Comment: Look like other people have the same bug https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3388 for me it also happens not each time when program finishes.

Comment: What is your keras version.? Python version.? Tensorflow version.?

Comment: Add the full traceback and the code snippet where this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by the Cache file, you can try deleting the **pycache** folder. This works for me.
I am using the Tensorflow version.